# Не обновляется WAR файл

Tags: java, maven, war

Всех приветствую. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на сервере приложений у меня есть файл "WAR". Если выпустить новую версию, то старый "WAR" не обновляется. Приходится удалять старый, чтобы он подгрузил новый. pom.xml

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-bundles</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <!--  download jbpm-designer.war -->
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jbpm-designer-backend</artifactId>
                  <type>war</type>
                  <destFileName>jbpm-designer.war</destFileName>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
```

**В maven bulder установлена в pom.xml новая версия**

```
    <properties>
    <webbpm.hotswap.version>1.12</webbpm.hotswap.version>
    <jbpm-designer.version>6.2.0.Final-Center.24</jbpm-designer.version>
    <controlsfx.version>8.40.12</controlsfx.version>
    <testfx.version>4.0.11-alpha</testfx.version>
    <java.cef.version>3.36.1</java.cef.version>
    <jgit.version>5.3.0.201903130848-r</jgit.version>
    <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Поменяйте директорию.

Comment: @RomanC не совсем понял. Можно подробнее?